# Nokogiri CSS normalization

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

I have some attributes like:

```
<span style="font:22px Arial">...</span>
```

and others like:

```
<span style="font-size:22px;font-family:Arial">...</span>
```

Now I can get the style attribute with nokogiri, but what I'd want is to the following information:

- font-family
- font-size
- color
- text-decoration
- font-weight
- font-style

Some attributes like color are easy to get, but some others, like font-size, require quite some tinkering with the css string.

Before digging into a solution of my own, I was wondering if nokogiri, or perhaps a specialized css gem would be able to normalize the css string and let me query the css attributes one by one. It would be even more convenient if I could get the computed css (for example an element with no font-size inside an element with a font-size of 10 would give me 10 when I ask for the font-size on the child element), but this last part is easy to implement with a hash and a stack, so it's not very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot of different things, I ended writing my own solution from scratch.

For future reference, here is how I did it:

- use Nokogiri's `doc.traverse` to traverse the document
- each time I encounter a text node, I do something like `parents = []; parent = node.parent; while parent do parents << parent; parent = parent.parent; end; result << {:text => node.text, :parents => parents}`
- finally for each text chunk in my result array, I cycle the parents and manually analyze each node, setting style one by one, for example, font the font-size:

  ```
      css = node[:style]
      if not style[:font_size] # style is a hash applied to each text chunk, the first encountered parent that define it wins
          if node.name == 'font' and node[:size]
              style[:font_size] = node[:size].to_i * 5
          elsif css =~ /font-size:[^;\d]*(\d*)/
              style[:font_size] = $1.to_i
          elsif css =~ /font:[^;\d]*(\d*)/
              style[:font_size] = $1.to_i
          end
      end
  ```

It wasn't really hard to handle all the browser cases, it just took a systemic approach. The final implementation for font-size is about 5 times longer (to handle units...). Unfortunately I cannot release the complete source code. But I hope it will answer the question for those who lands on it.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. The JavaScript DOM parser would be able to do this nicely, but I don't know if Ruby can. The [css_parser gem](https://github.com/alexdunae/css_parser) might be a starting point, but I don't know if it can process inline styles...

And of course, inline styles like these are evil, partly because they're hard to normalize. Replace with a stylesheet as soon as possible, if this is your own markup.

Comment: I agree that replacing with a stylesheet is the best idea. In that case, Nokogiri can be good when extracting the currently defined styles, and for rewriting the file to remove the `style` parameter from the tags.

Comment: Right. Or rather, probably not Nokogiri, but whatever CSS parser you wind up with.

Comment: Actually...if this is a one-off (or at least, if it doesn't need to be integrated into your Ruby app), you might be better off writing this in JavaScript or CoffeeScript (or HotRuby!) and running in the browser so you have access to `getComputedStyle`.

Comment: The idea is to avoid a headless browser. The html is generated by a WYSIWYG editor we don't have control over.

Comment: Understood, but in this case, a browser engine is probably the best solution, due to your need for CSS parsing. Hmm. And for that matter, what's your use case like that you don't have control over the HTML but need to normalize it?

Comment: We use the content_editable feature of browser in the editor, and each browser implementation is different. Safari generates <font face=... tags instead of css (not always, it's a bit "random").

Comment: About the headless browser, this is how we are currently rendering the contents, but it requires a lot of dependencies and we don't have full control over it.   Eventually, we will rewrite an html5 editor that will generate a saner markup.

Comment: Ah...so you're trying to normalize user-entered HTML generated with contentEditable (which I hadn't been aware of...cool!)?

Answer (score 1):

No, Nokogiri has no such capabilities to perform this. You want the equivalent of JavaScript's [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) implemented in Ruby, which would require a Ruby library that knows how to parse HTML and CSS, and apply CSS rules to an HTML document.

**Edit**: You might try using JRuby along with [Celerity](http://celerity.rubyforge.org/) for a headless web browser.